# How to make Transform and Draggable work together?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there anyway to make work `Draggable` widget with `Transform` ? I tried to combine it to make it work. I tried putting Transform inside `Draggable` but it still starts drag where `the painted place` cross with `the original place of element's position without translate`. I also tried putting `Draggable` inside of `Transform` and its the same. How to inform draggable of the fact that element is painted with `Matrix4.translate` ?

```
Transform(
    origin: Offset(0,0),
    transform: rotateAndTranslate(),
    child: Draggable<int>(data: "rectangle", child: GameCard(cardWidth), feedback: GameCard(cardWidth), childWhenDragging: Container(width: cardWidth,), onDragStarted: () { ImDragged(); },)
```

or if I put Transform into Draggable it will be the same effect.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone will find this problematic it could be really trivial like in my scenerio. The `parent` of the `Transform` element is actually the entry "hitbox" that checks if its child was "tapped". So if you will ever try using `Draggable` with `Transform` make sure your `Transform` after using "translate/rotate etc" will still be within area of the parent.